# Tag returns null when trying to write NDEF message to NFC tag - Tag is not detected

Tags: android, android-intent, tags, nfc, ndef

I am trying to write an NDEF message to a tag. Below is the code that I have. I run the code using the debugger in my IDE, but after executing the line

```
Tag tag = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);
```

`tag` is `null` (I assume this means that no tag was found) and I am not able to write the NDEF message. Instead I get a NullPointerException.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;
    private NfcAdapter mNfcAdapter;
    static final byte[] TYPE_BT_OOB = "application/vnd.bluetooth.ep.oob".
            getBytes(Charset.forName("US_ASCII"));
    private NdefMessage mNdefMessage;
    String mLocalBluetoothAddress;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mNfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);
        mNdefMessage = createHandoverRequestMessage();
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        //Intent intent = new Intent();

        String action = intent.getAction();
        Tag tag = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);// I am getting only Null in tag here//
        try {
            Ndef ndef = Ndef.get(tag);
            ndef.connect();
            try {
                ndef.writeNdefMessage(mNdefMessage);
            } catch (FormatException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            ndef.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("TagDispatch", e.toString());
        }
    }
```

And this is my Manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.nfcdemov5"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk  android:minSdkVersion="16" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.nfc" android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" 
        android:debuggable="true" >

        <activity
            android:name="com.example.nfcdemov5.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >

          <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <data android:mimeType="application/vnd.bluetooth.ep.oob" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: What data is on your tag (before)? Are you starting the activity by tapping the tag or is your activity already visible in the foreground? Do you use `enableForegroundDispatch()`? If yes, show the relevant code (from `onResume()`, `onPause()`, `onNewIntent()`).

Comment: Thanks Michael for the response. Tag does not have any data. My only objective is to write NDEF into the tag. Apologies -I am new to app development and to NFC as well.

Comment: Okay then, so what exactly are you doing right now? You start the app manually (by clicking the launcher icon)? Or does the app start when you touch the tag? Does the app do anything when you touch the tag? Again, is this all the code of your activity or is there more?

Comment: Apart from the code given above, I have code for preparing NDEF message  - createHandoverRequestMessage() which is to pair with bluetooth device. I am not able to share the code as it is too long. I tried to execute by connecting my NFC enabled phone and placing it on the tag in which I want to write NDEF message. It was not doing anything. So I tried using debugger ON. After the Tag(tag) statement and once it gets into the try portion it throws nullexception error. when I checked the value of tag it is showing as null.

Comment: The action that is there after intent.getaction () is "android.intent.action.MAIN". I am not sure if this will help you go advise me.

Comment: So to summarize this, you start the app by starting the debugger, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NFC events are triggered by touching an NFC tag. Hence, when you open your app by clicking the launcher icon (or by starting it from your development environment), ANdroid won't generate an NFC event (even if your device is was already placed on top of the tag).

Hence, what you need to do is to register your app for NFC events. You can do this either through the manifest or while your app is running in the foreground, through the foreground dispatch system. As it seems as you want to be able to write to just any tag, regardless of what data is currently on it, I would suggest that you stick to the foreground dispatch system and do not register for any NFC event in your AndroidManifest.xml.

You would first register to receive an event for *any* tag using the `enableForegroundDispatch()` method in `onResume()`:

```
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    NfcAdapter nfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this, getClass()).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP), 0);
    nfcAdapter.enableForegroundDispatch(this, pendingIntent, null, null);
}
```

Moreover, you have to disable the foreground dispatch again, before your activity leaves the foreground (hence, in `onPause()`):

```
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    NfcAdapter nfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);
    nfcAdapter.disableForegroundDispatch(this);
}
```

Finally, you can process the tag from the `onNewIntent()` method. Hence, you would **move** the code that you currently have to process the tag from `onCreate()` to `onNewIntent()`:

```
public void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        Tag tag = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);
        if (tag != null) {
            Ndef ndef = Ndef.get(tag);
            if (ndef != null) {
                try {
                    ndef.connect();
                    ndef.writeNdefMessage(createHandoverRequestMessage());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("TagWriting", e.toString());
                } finally {
                    try {
                        ndef.close();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                    }
                }   
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You could further refine this by performing the actual writing on a separate thread, as blocking IO operations should not be performed on the UI thread as they may cause your app to freeze.

Comment: I tried the above code. I just changed "ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED" to ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED and it is going into "if" loop. But while writing into the tag it is throwing IO exception=> java.io.IOException.

Comment: You should get TAG_DISCOVERED and not NDEF_DISCOVERED when using the above code. The IOException could occur if your phone looses contact with the tag (e.g. if the tag is not properly placed on the phone or if removed while writing) or if the NDEF message is too large to fit on the tag.

Comment: Sorry. initially I tried with a tag which has some content and so it was not TAG_DISCOVERED and throwing IO exception. Now I tried with a new tag and intent was TAG_DISCOVERED and also able to write NDEF message. Thank you Roland for the help.. Now I need to check if the NDEF message written in the Tag works :). Thanks a ton.

Comment: @abdullahicyc Please refrain from hijacking other questions. If you have a new question, feel free to ask one here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask (also see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)